# Nested typedef, what's wrong

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Does somebody see error here. Whats wrong with this `typedef A<B<T>::c>`??

```
template <const char *N> struct A { static const char *p; };
template <const char *N> const char *A<N>::p = N;
template <class T> struct B { static const char c[1]; typedef A<B<T>::c> C; };
template <class T> const char B<T>::c[1] = "";
template <class T> struct D { static const char c[1]; typedef A<c> C; };
template <class T> const char D<T>::c[1] = "";

template <int& I> struct E { static int *ip; };
template <int& I> int* E<I>::ip = &I;
template <class T> struct F { static int i; typedef E<F<T>::i> C; };
template <class T> int F<T>::i;
template <class T> struct G { static int i; typedef E<i> C; };
template <class T> int G<T>::i;

#define AS(X) if (!(X)) return 1;
int main()
{
  AS(B<int>::C::p == B<int>::c);
  AS(B<float>::C::p == B<float>::c);
  AS(B<float>::C::p != B<int>::c);
  AS(D<int>::C::p == D<int>::c);
  AS(D<float>::C::p == D<float>::c);
  AS(D<float>::C::p != D<int>::c);
}
```

Comment: it compiles for me, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Post the error or problem you are facing.

Comment: http://ideone.com/yZAwK - post your compiler version and error you get.

Comment: I am use android NDK compiler.

Comment: I recive internal compiler error
Compiler: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: I can't see any error, and neither can my compiler. What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. There's a bug in your compiler and you should ensure this bug is reported to the developers.